# Rails custom URL with username

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have added this route at the bottom of `routes.rb`:

```
get ':username' => 'user#show'
```

And I have also updated the controller to use `params[:username]` to find the user.

Now the problem is the following:

```
link_to 'Foo', @user # => /users/123
```

How can I configure the *User* model to be always converted to `/foo`?

Note; I know about `to_param`, but that would generate `/users/foo`, which is not what I need.

Answer (score -1):

in your routes

> get '/users/:id', to: 'users#show', as: 'username'

in your controller
you will not receive the id as `params[:username]`

> @user = User.find(params[:id])

Finally in your view

> link_to 'Foo', username_path(@user)

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#generating-paths-and-urls-from-code